# Redirect back to AssertionConsumerService gives 302

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

When redirected back from NemIdLogin to AssertionConsumerService it comes with status code 302 before then being the status code 405 with GET method instead of POST...

What happened was yesterday we uploaded a new SP metadata file but I made a mistake and had the localhost as a base url to AssertionConsumerService and SingleLogoutService, so I had to fix that and reuploaded the exact same file except I changed from localhost to correct values....

Before I did that the redirect back to localhost worked fine, but as soon as the new file with correct base url was uploaded we started getting the 302 and then 405 when redirected back.

And now no matter what I do to the metadata file and reupload it, it still gives the same response, first 302 then 405

Do you know why that might be the case? Something to do with the first file being uploaded with localhost and that was somehow cached somewhere in the NemIdLogin admin portal or something?

Answer (score 0):

It sound like the endpoint uploaded in the metadata file is incorrect.
You can use fiddler to trace if the IdP (NemLog-in) calls the correct endpoints.

Othervice you can try to test with the [NemLog-in sample](https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2/tree/master/test/TestWebAppCoreNemLogin3Sp). You can change the sample apps port and issuer to match what you have configured in NemLog-in.

Alternatively, I can recommend you to convert the NemLog-in SAML 2.0 integration to OpenID Connect by adding [FoxIDs](https://www.foxids.com/docs) as an Identity Broker in between NemLog-in and your application. Docs on how to connect [FoxIDs to NemLog-in](https://www.foxids.com/docs/up-party-howto-saml-2.0-nemlogin).

Comment: Well that's the thing, the endpoint is not incorrect.... I've verified that multiple times. I've been using fiddler, it all looks good except that it gives first 302 then 405
I'll try your other recommendations now, thanks

Comment: Hi again, just to let you know, we get the same behavior if we use your code and change the issuer, we get back first 302 then 405

Comment: Hi Anders, I just wanted to inform you that my issue went away without me doing anything, I did not upload a new metadata file, did not deploy new code, nothing. I just started working... which is frustrating because I was banging my head against the wall for several hours now...
Have you by any chance experienced something similar? As if there's some sort of caching in the NemLogin admin portal or something...

Comment: I think there was some problem locally in your development environment that now is gone away. No I haven't tried anything similar I'm afraid.